# How to use UserDefaults.standard save custom Data?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

My Data Class

```
import Foundation

class People {

let peopleImage : String
let peopleTime : Int
let peopleName : String

init(image:String, second:Int, name:String) {

    peopleImage = image
    peopleTime = second
    peopleName = name

}
```

My Data List File

```
import Foundation

class CustomPeopleList {

    var peopleList = [

        People(image: "Man", second: 12, name: "Andy"),
        People(image: "Woman", second: 60, name: "Kevin"),



    ]

}
```

my viewController :

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard    
var allPeopleList = CustomPeopleList
```

There is a button, when I click button it will delete the first item in the Data List, but I find it always error. my userdefault code is this:

```
self.allPeopleList.remove(at: indexPathTimer.row)
let aaa = self.allPeopleList
let newPeopleData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.allPeopleList)
self.defaults.set(aaa, forKey: "myPeopleData")
```

and when i want to use it

```
if let peopleData = defaults.data(forKey: "myPeopleData") as? [People] {
allPeopleList = peopleData
}
var allPeopleList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: peopleData!) as? [Peoples]
```

the xcode say it wrong

Comment: Not really sure what the issue you are having is but i did notice in your last line of code you have [Peoples] but the class name is 'People' not 'Peoples'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, then the objects you archive must subclass `NSObject` and conform to `NSCoding`.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
class People: NSObject, NSCoding {

    let peopleImage : String
    let peopleTime : Int
    let peopleName : String

    init(image:String, second:Int, name:String) {
        peopleImage = image
        peopleTime = second
        peopleName = name
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.peopleImage = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "peopleImage") as! String
        self.peopleTime = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "peopleTime")
        self.peopleName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "peopleName") as! String
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.peopleImage, forKey: "peopleImage")
        aCoder.encode(self.peopleTime, forKey: "peopleTime")
        aCoder.encode(self.peopleName, forKey: "peopleName")
    }
}

class CustomPeopleList: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var peopleList = [
        People(image: "Man", second: 12, name: "Andy"),
        People(image: "Woman", second: 60, name: "Kevin"),
    ]

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.peopleList = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "peopleList") as! [People]
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.peopleList, forKey: "peopleList")
    }

}

var allPeopleList = CustomPeopleList()

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: allPeopleList)
```

**However**

Implementing `NSCoding` can be very verbose.

If your objects include basic entities, like integers, strings, and arrays/dictionaries of encodable entities, then it may be easier to use Swift's new `Codable` protocol.

The advantage of this method is that if your objects are simple, then Swift can generate the encode and decode methods for you.

I personally recommend `Codable`. It can be much simpler than the old `NSCoding` method.

That would look like this:

```
class People: Codable {

    let peopleImage : String
    let peopleTime : Int
    let peopleName : String

    init(image:String, second:Int, name:String) {
        peopleImage = image
        peopleTime = second
        peopleName = name
    }
}

class CustomPeopleList: Codable {

    var peopleList = [
        People(image: "Man", second: 12, name: "Andy"),
        People(image: "Woman", second: 60, name: "Kevin"),
    ]

}

var allPeopleList = CustomPeopleList()

// Can save in whatever format you want. JSON is always light and simple.
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(allPeopleList)

// Decode the data object later.
let decodedPeopleList = try JSONDecoder().decode(CustomPeopleList.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I don't know how to say thank you to ABeard89 & vadian, you guys are genies! Thank you !!!!!!! I am almost cry!

Comment: @BangoSingh I’m glad it worked! Glad to help. I’m sure vadian is too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `Codable` protocol and to save the data as JSON. It's *swiftier* than Obj-C related `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver`

- Adopt the protocol

  ```
  class People : Codable {
  ```
- Encode the array as JSON and save it

  ```
  do {        
     let newPeopleData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.allPeopleList)
     self.defaults.set(newPeopleData, forKey: "myPeopleData")
  } catch { print(error)
  ```
- To read the data is very simple, too

  ```
  do {
     if let newPeopleData = self.defaults.data(forKey: "myPeopleData") {
        allPeopleList = try JSONDecoder().decode([People].self, from: newPeopleData)
     }
  } catch { print(error)
  ```

Note: I'd name the class in singular form `Person` because an array of People (`[People]`) is tautologic and to name the properties `image`, `time` and `name`.

Comment: You beat me to it! I also recommend `Codable` with JSON.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I don't know how to say thank you to ABeard89 & vadian, you guys are genies! Thank you !!!!!!! I am almost cry!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit `People` class from NSObject when you are using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` or `NSKeyedArchiver`.

To store custom object in userdefaaults you need to inherit custom class form `NSObject` otherwise you will get runtime error/crashes.

```
class People: NSObject {


}
```